# How can I truncate a string at the first instance of a character?

Tags: c#, .net, string

I currently have a string `1_0707201206050239` and I would like to truncate all the characters to the right of and including the `_` char.

The issue is that the characters on the left hand side vary based on user input so the length of the string is always different. The right hand side of `_` represents a date and time (e.g. `07-07-2012 6:05:02.390AM`) the length can vary from 17-14 characters.

So I'm wondering if there's a way to truncate until the `_` is detected?

Comment: trunctate until? or including and after, your question is not consistent - substring in combination with IndexOf is probably the best way to go

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
text.Substring(0, text.IndexOf('_'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use:

```
String.Substring(0, String.indexOf('_'));
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using String.Remove

```
theString = theString.Remove(sourceString.IndexOf('_'), 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this, which returns the entire string if the character(s) don't occur in the string:

```
static class StringExtensions
{
    internal static string TruncateAtFirst(this string str, params char [] ch)
    {
        int i = str.IndexOfAny(ch);
        return (i < 0 ? str : str.Substring(0, i));
    }
}

"abcdefg".TruncateAtFirst('c')      // "ab" 
"abcdefg".TruncateAtFirst('e', 'b') // "a"
"abcdefg".TruncateAtFirst('z')      // "abcdefg"
       "".TruncateAtFirst('z')      // ""
```

Easy to do with strings as well.

Comment: dude, this question is >6 years old... and it already has an answer

Comment: None of the accepted answers are fault-tolerant. I'm offering what I believe to be a better solution. And I got a badge for it, so this must be acceptable. :-)